# Override new button aura wrapper with lwc functions does not work

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, button-overrides

I am overriding new button with aura and using inside aura my lwc. But I cann't invoke any lwc fucntion. I added debug points, but they are not triggered. So it seems that methods are not called at all. Connected callback works.

NewButton.cmp

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride"
               

    <aura:handler name="init"
                  value="{!this}"
                  action="{!c.init}"
    />

    <lwcCmp aura:id="lwcCmp"/>
</aura:component>
```

Helper

```
({
init: function (component) {
    const helper = this;
    component.find('lwcCmp').unregisterAllListeners();
}
})
```

lwcCmp

```
import {api, LightningElement} from 'lwc';


export default class LwcCmp extends LightningElement {
    connectedCallback(){
        debugger;
    }
    @api method() {
        debugger;
    }
}
```

UPD:
Also i found out that it works with setTimeout. Any ideas how to wait for render lwc?

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride"
       <c:lwcCmp aura:id="lwcCmp"/>
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your markup to call lwc component has typo. In an Aura component, to refer to either Aura components or Lightning web components, use camel case with a colon separating the namespace and the component name.

Your code is:-

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride"
   <lwcCmp aura:id="lwcCmp"/>
</aura:component>
```

Right code would be:-

```
<aura:component implements="force:hasRecordId,lightning:actionOverride"
       <c:lwcCmp aura:id="lwcCmp"/>
</aura:component>
```

Read more here :- [Compose Aura Components from Lightning Web Components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.interop_aura_composition)

### Update

Coming to your second issue, You need to make sure lwc is loaded, then only it will be available to access from dom in aura component.

To achieve that, one way to do so is, fire an event from lwc when it is done with loading. listen to that event from aura and calls other method from lwc in the event handler in aura controller.

A working example can be found here:- [PASSING VALUE FROM LWC TO PARENT AURA COMPONENT](https://salesforcediaries.com/2019/09/16/passing-value-from-lwc-to-parent-aura-component/)

Comment: I missed it  and it doesnt work anyway. I  found that it works with setTimeout.

Comment: @fedove, Please see my updated answer.